# IIS Web Deployment ASP.net Web Application vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7

I have created a vb.net Web Application. The application is running from Visual Studio. When I try to host the application. It gives me the error Default.aspx.vb file is missing. But the compilation mode is `explicit=true` in my config file. My Deployment Folder doesn't have any vb files. I have bin folder with my application dll. I am new to .net application. Please help me . Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <siteMap>
          <providers>
            <add name="stock" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Stock.sitemap"/>
          </providers>
        </siteMap>
    </system.web>        
</configuration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, i created a web application from template and deleted the default.aspx and created the same default.aspx again. Now i deleted the default.aspx and created the same page as login.aspx . Now it is working fine. Thanks all for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your .aspx file has the following definition in the `<%@ Page` at the top:

```
CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb"
```

If it says `CodeFile` and not `CodeBehind` that is your problem.